# duplicate symbols for architecture i386 and couldn't find same name of Class and file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

When I compiled my iPhone app with Xcode 4.6, I see a strange error code:

> "duplicate symbols for architecture i386".

I know this issue about duplication of file name or class name. so I tried to find the file by using the search bar in Finder.  I also tried to search for duplicated classes with the search bar in Xcode, however I could't find it.  I already checked that I'm not importing .m files.

What should I do next? please give any advice.

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: There should be a little extra bit about _OBJC_CLASS_$_SomeClass.o.  There's your dupe.

Comment: duplicate symbol _FormatTypeTime in:
    /Users/TakuyaTakahashi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ITPOSMOBILE-azsoqgumbqsbhqdzykxvselnxfvj/Build/Intermediates/ITPOSMOBILE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ITPOSMOBILE.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
    /Users/TakuyaTakahashi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ITPOSMOBILE-azsoqgumbqsbhqdzykxvselnxfvj/Build/Intermediates/ITPOSMOBILE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ITPOSMOBILE.build/Objects-normal/i386/ITSDatePickerCell.o
ld: 464 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: This is one of complete error message. and I realized new thing which new duplicated error is appeared after i delete a file which might be duplicated. In This case, if I delete ITSDatePickerCell, and then another file name is appeared as duplicated file.

Comment: It looks like every files are duplicated.

Comment: I could resolve this issue myself. I declare  "NSString * const FormatTypeTime = @"~~~~~";" in the header file. I should declare "static NSString * const FormatTypeTime = @"~~~~~";" i forgot to use "static". and I used this variable in the lots of file. that's the reason why every files looked like duplicated. Thank for answering my question!

Answer (score 13):

I could resolve this issue myself.

I declare  in the header file.

> NSString * const FormatTypeTime = @"~~~~~";

I should declare

> static NSString * const FormatTypeTime = @"~~~~~";

I forgot to use "**static**". and I used this variable in the lots of file. that's the reason why every files looked like duplicated.

Thank for answering my question!

Comment: Can someone exmplain why this happens without using "static" keyword?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when a file with same name gets compiled twice.

Go to Project Target-> Build Phases->Look for multiple occurrences of same file under "Compile Sources". You can search for file name there as well.

Remove multiple occurrences from there.

If file is added multiple times in your project then remove duplicate files & keep only one.

Answer (score 1):

The error shows that in any 2 of your files a variable name( or method name ) are duplicated which have global scope. You can solve this by,

*)Renaming the variable or method

OR

*)Change the scope of variable or method to local ( By adding the declaration statement to interface section of .m file. )